# What's wrong with my MYSQL Code query in php file?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables in mysql database

one table named is place:

| place_id | place | active | shortform | country | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Uttar Pradesh | 1 | UP | India | State |
| 2 | Delhi | 1 | DELHI | India | Union territory |
| 3 | Punjab | 1 | PUN | India | State |
| 4 | Karnataka | 1 | KAR | India | State |
| 5 | Kerala | 1 | KER | India | State |
| 6 | Lucknow | 1 | LKO | India | Capital |
| 7 | Chandigarh | 1 | CHA | India | Capital |
| 8 | Bengaluru | 1 | BEN | India | Capital |
| 9 | Thiruvanthapuram | 1 | THI | India | Capital |
| 10 | Saharanpur | 1 | SAH | India | District |
| 11 | Meerut | 1 | MEE | India | District |
| 12 | Gorakhpur | 1 | GOR | India | District |

and other named as place_capital

| id_place_place | place_parent | place_child |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 3 | 7 |
| 3 | 4 | 8 |
| 4 | 5 | 9 |
| 5 | 1 | 10 |
| 6 | 1 | 11 |
| 7 | 1 | 12 |

I run this query

```
select *, group_concat(place_capital.place_child) AS Group from place
left join place_capital on place.place_id = place_place.place_parent
where place.place_id = place_place.place_parent and active = :active AND type = :type
group by place ORDER BY place
```

and it give the following result

| place_id | place | active | shortform | country | type | id_place_place | place_parent | place_child | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Uttar Pradesh | 1 | UP | India | State | 1 | 1 | 6 | 6,10,11,12 |
| 3 | Punjab | 1 | PUN | India | State | 2 | 3 | 7 | NULL |
| 4 | Karnataka | 1 | KAR | India | State | 3 | 4 | 8 | NULL |
| 5 | Kerala | 1 | KER | India | State | 4 | 5 | 9 | NULL |

What query I used in php file to give the following result that include **Delhi** also.
The **place table** have some relationship with **place_place table**. with my above sql query that not give the Delhi in the result. So, what is the thing I missed in the php file to get the below result.

| place_id | place | active | shortform | country | type | id_place_place | place_parent | place_child | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Uttar Pradesh | 1 | UP | India | State | 1 | 1 | 6 | 6,10,11,12 |
| 2 | Delhi | 1 | DELHI | India | Union Territory | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | Punjab | 1 | PUN | India | State | 2 | 3 | 7 | NULL |
| 4 | Karnataka | 1 | KAR | India | State | 3 | 4 | 8 | NULL |
| 5 | Kerala | 1 | KER | India | State | 4 | 5 | 9 | NULL |

and here is the code in the php file:-

```
public function __construct(Querier $db, $type = "", $active = 1) {
    $this->db = $db;
    $this->type = $type;
    $this->active = $active;

    $connection = $this->db->getConnection();

    if ($this->type != "") {
        $statement = $connection->prepare("select *, group_concat(place_capital.place_child) AS Group from place
                                        left join place_capital on place.place_id = place_place.place_parent
                                        where place.place_id = place_place.place_parent and active = :active AND type = :type
                                        group by place ORDER BY place ");
        $statement->bindParam(":type", $this->type);
    } else {
        $statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM place WHERE active = :active ORDER BY place ");
    }

    $statement->bindParam(":active", $this->active);
    $statement->execute();
    $this->_guide_list = $statement->fetchAll();

}
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question what parameters you used for active and type in your queries. Btw your query is against the sql standard an only runs because you do not have only full group by sql mode enabled.

Comment: _on place.place_id = place_place.place_parent where place.place_id = place_place.place_parent_  This is a repeat

Comment: In prepare statement I what I use to give the relevant result that include the delhi row also

Comment: When I use single time it give all the 12 rows also. When I use it give the group result in 5 rows@SimoneRossaini

Comment: When I use in mysql console it give the result that not include the Delhi in that result

Answer (score 0):

As I can see here you only filter based on state and Delhi is Union Territory so to include that in a list you need to use In operator to filter type. you can also skip a join condition from where clause.

```
SELECT *,
   Group_concat(place_capital.place_child) AS Group
FROM   place
   left join place_capital
          ON place.place_id = place_capital.place_parent
WHERE active = 1
   AND TYPE IN ('State', 'Union Territory')
GROUP  BY place.place_id
ORDER  BY place.place_id
```

Comment: I try but it give all the 12 rows.

Comment: I want to show the place_parent that have the relationship with different place as mentioned in place column in table place and the relationship is showing in table place_place. with my query it give the result place_parent with using group code it showing the child relationship with the place_parent but I want to show the delhi also that not have any relationship with any other place it is not included in the place_place table also.

Comment: I just added a small correction in above query in group by and order by I added it based on id. There are only two tables place & place_capital. Which one is place_place table?

Comment: If your query is working as expected and only you want to include Delhi then you can try with below where condition.

where active = 1 AND type In ('State', 'Union Territory')